# Manually built eclipse plugin doesn't appear to update in target

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I installed the RCP variant of Eclipse 2019-06.

I checked out the source for an Eclipse plugin that I know has a problem.  I'm pretty sure I know what the fix is, so I changed the line in the source to fix the problem.  I then did a "Project->Clean", and then I exported "Deployable plug-ins and fragments" to a directory.  From that exported directory, from the "plugins" subdir, I found a plugin jar.  I copied that into the "dropins" directory of the same Eclipse distribution.

I then started that Eclipse instance and tested the operation in the plugin.  The behavior didn't change.  In fact, the stacktrace in the error log didn't change from before the fix, and it now points to a line that is not executable, so it's clear that the installed plugin is still using the old code.

I even decompiled the class file in the resulting exported plugin jar and confirmed that it had the fix I made.  It seems like Eclipse is caching the class files for the imported plugin somewhere.

What can I do to troubleshoot this, or fix the problem?

**Update**:

Concerning the question about whether Eclipse copied the jar from the dropins folder to the plugins folder, I note that in recent versions of Eclipse including now, the contents of the plugins folder only has a single jar file no matter what, being "org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.400.v20190515-0925.jar".

Concerning the question about changing the version number, no, I did not change the version number.  How do I do that properly?  Is it enough to change the version number in the jar file name, or do I have to change the number in one or more of the metadata files in the project?

Concerning the comment about troubleshooting this with the OSGi console, can you give me a little more information?

**Update**:

I think I've resolved this.  Pursuant to the version comment, I changed the version number in the manifest.mf from 1.1.0 to 1.1.1, cleaned the project, and reexported, and the now 1.1.1 jar file inserted into dropins has fixed the problem.

Comment: Did Eclipse actually copy the plugin from the dropins folder to the plugins folder? Did you change the version number of the plugin?

Comment: If it is not the version number it has been missed to increment, you can troubleshoot this via the OSGi console (`-console`) by installing and starting this plug-in/bundle manually.

Comment: I updated the post with information around the questions in these comments.